# Application starting in elixir

Tags: elixir

From docs:

```
def application do
  [mod: {MyApp, []}]
end
```

> Often times, an application defines a supervision tree that must be
>   started and stopped when the application starts and stops. For such,
>   we need to define an application module callback. The first step is to
>   define the module callback in the application definition in the
>   mix.exs file:

But from docs there it is unclear, what is the list (second argument) after MyApp.

Should it be list of my modules which implement `GenServer` Behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value in the tuple is the argument that's passed to `MyApp.start/2` as the second argument.

If you make that:

```
def application do
  [mod: {MyApp, [:foo, :bar]}]
end
```

and then in `MyApp.start`, inspect the second argument (named `args` by the default `mix` generator):

```
def start(_type, args) do
    IO.inspect args
    ...
end
```

and then run `mix`, you'll see:

```
$ mix
[:foo, :bar]
```